# for in loop not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

I have an array sessionValue which is as follows:

```
document.write(sessionValue);

Array ( [Finance] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 3 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
[Human resources] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 )
[Infrastructure] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 3 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) ) 1
```

Retrieving session value and Printing array in the javascript page using for...in loop :

JSpage.js

```
sessionValue = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["Count"]); ?>';
document.write(sessionValue);
document.write("<br />");
for(var s1 in sessionValue) {
for(var s in sessionValue[s1]) {
    document.write(s);
}}
```

Gives output:

```
{"Finance":[0,3,0,0,1],"Human resources":[1,5,1,0,0],"Infrastructure":[0,3,1,0,0]}
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

And if the for...in loop is written as follows :

```
for(var s1 in sessionValue) {
for(var s in sessionValue[s1]) {

    document.write(sessionValue[s1][s]);
    document.write("<br />");
}}
```

Gives output:

```
{"Finance":[0,3,0,0,1],"Human resources":[1,5,1,0,0],"Infrastructure":[0,3,1,0,0]}
{
"
F
i
n
a
n
c
e
"
:
[
0
, 
3
,
```

and it goes on to print whole array.I believe it considers it as string even though i used json_encode().

I want to retrieve the key eg. Finance and the inner array values. How to solve this?

Comment: You're setting sessionValue to a string here: `sessionValue = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["Count"]); ?>';` You'll need to output it correctly as an object. Just remove the single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

It's a string because you put single quotes around it:

```
sessionValue = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["Count"]); ?>'
```

Remove those quotes to get an object instead:

```
var sessionValue = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["Count"]); ?>;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the generated javascript in the browser. You would see that

```
sessionValue = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["Count"]); ?>';
```

produces

```
sessionValue = '{"Finance":[0,3,0,0,1],"Human resources":[1,5,1,0,0],"Infrastructure":[0,3,1,0,0]}';
```

which indeed is a string value

```
sessionValue = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["Count"]); ?>;
```

would on the other hand produce an object literal (no plings)

```
sessionValue = {"Finance":[0,3,0,0,1],"Human resources":[1,5,1,0,0],"Infrastructure":[0,3,1,0,0]}
```

with that said you should never use a `for in`loop to iterate over an array in JS because it no only iterates over the elements in the array but also all other properties, which is at least `length`

so aside from the above change you should also consider rewritting your iteratiosn to

```
for(var s1 in sessionValue) {
    if(sessionValue.hasOwnProperty(s1)){
        var arr = sessionValue[s1]
        for(var len=arr.length,i=0; i<len; i = i +1) {
            document.write(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```